# Randomizing webpages with math.random

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a wepsite where you have 35 webpages with a song playing. I then have 4 possible answers on the page and when you click on any one of them it will take you to another of my pages randomly.However I want it to only go to each page ones and when it has went through all of them it shall link to a new page. Can anyone help me?

Javascript:

```
    function myFunction() {

var no=Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)
 window.location.href = "Sang"+no+".html";}
```

So I have changed the javascript. Now it is more simple.

One of my webpages:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Gæt en sang</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script src="Test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <audio class="hidden" controls autoplay>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="pokemon.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
        <div id="header">
            <h2> Gæt sangen og hejs flagstangen!</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="left">
        <ul> Hvilken sang er dette?

            </br>
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">
            <li> World we must defend </li>
            </button>
            </br>
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">
            <li> Pokemon theme</li>
            </button>
            </br>
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">
            <li> Gotta Catch 'em All<li>
            </button>
            </br>
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">
            <li> You teach me i teach you <li>
    </button>
        </ul>
        </div>
   </div>
    <p id="Test"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: By calling `Math.random()` 35 times (instead of storing it in a variable) you exponentially reduce the probability of getting the next song. That means you will probably never get the last song while the first ones will appear almost everytime.

Comment: you can't change your code it will invalidates the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't kill JavaScript.
There are lots of problems with your code.
You need to use `(Math.random() * 36)` as Sebastien C. suggests in comment:

```
 var no=Math.floor((Math.random() * 36) + 1)
 window.location.href = "Sang"+no+".html";
```

Better to make a clean logic first. Then try to apply it.

Comment: But ofc, if all pages have the same name, better to create array just with numbers.

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random): `Math.random() function returns [...] in the range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive)`. It's impossible to have `no` > 35. You can remove the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you need to persist a list of visited pages. There are many ways. You could use cookies or local storage or even a database. The easiest thing might be to append a query string to the URL after each visit. A possible example:

```
window.location.href = 'sang3.html?visited=sang1,sang2,sang3';
```

Comment: how do I do this. Sorry I am quite new to java

Comment: @JakobSchøler where is java?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define them in list like

```
var pages = ['sang1.html', 'sang2.htm', ...]
```

Than call random so:

```
var page = Math.floor((Math.random() * pages.length) + 1)
window.location.href = pages[page]
pages.splice(page) // remove page from array
```

Comment: That won't persist between postbacks

Comment: okay I have done as you said but it still picks the same websites twice and sometimes i get an error where it can find undefined. I gues that means it has cycled through them but it really hasnt.